# How to check the process of an icon in the menu bar and and permanently remove it

Tags: menu-bar

In the top menu bar of Mac OS X, there is an icon what says "GuitarTricks.com". I am not sure how/when it gets into the menu bar but want to identify the process and understand how to disable it permanently. Another article tells CMD+Drag can remove it but would like to find out the process and how it got there. Using Apple Silicon M2 with Mac OSX 13.0.1.

[image]

Comment: Next step, update the OS. 13.0.1 was buggy as all heck & superseded months ago.

Comment: It looks like a video on a website that is playing in your browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is "Now Playing" button and it's not from an application, but shows what is currently playing. You can disable it in System Settings.app under Control Center tab. Here's the shreenshot:

[image: Now playing under Control Center tab in System Settings]